# Provide me regex to highlight word only once in a page

Tags: regex

Please provide me regex to highlight word only once in a page. I am using this for now:

```
highlightRegex = new RegExp("" + highlightWordsConcat + "(?!')", "ig");
```

I do not want to show words that has already highlighted on page.

Regards.

Comment: Do you know what `g` in `ig` does?

Comment: What language is this? Perhaps there is a non regex way of doing this that suits the language better. Select all interesting words and remove duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean by *highlighting*? And what do you think the regex you provided matches?

Answer (score 0):

Question is pretty vague but probably you're looking for something like this:

```
s = 'provide me regex to highlight word only once in a page, using regex only'
var r = s.replace(/(regex)/i, '<b>$1</b>');

console.log(r);
```

**OUTPUT:**

"provide me **regex** to highlight word only once in a page, using regex only"